# php многоуровневый ассоциативный массив и выборка

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, if

массив такого характера

```
array() {
[0] => {
array(3) {
["pk"]=>
string(8) "Abonents"
["fields"]=>
array(11) {
["sms"]=>
string(12) "+71234567890"
["name"]=>
string(52) "Петров Петя Петрович"
}
}
```

массив по rest api curl берет из биллинга я пытаюсь сделать поиск по номеру телефона и вывод значений того подмассива fields в котором есть этот номер
скрипт такой:

```
`<?php
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th,
table td {
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ФИО</td>
    <td>Номер телевона</td>
    <td>Номер договора</td>
    <td>Аккаунт ID</td>
</tr>
<?php
$phone = "+79122075335";
foreach ($extract as $key => $value) {
if($value == $phone) {
echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$key['fields']['create_date'].'</td>
         <td>'.$key['fields']['name'].'</td>
         <td>'.$key['fields']['sms'].'</td>
         <td>'.$key['fields']['contract_number'].'</td>
         <td>'.$key['fields']['account_id'].'</td>
         <td></td>
</tr>';
}
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

но у меня выходит пустая таблица пожалуйста подскажите где ошибка, я в пхп новичек...

Comment: попробуйте $value['fields']['create_date'] etc.

Comment: спасибо работает сейчас прикручиваю кнопку сабмит выдает пустую таблицу

Comment: сама кнопка <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<form action="name.php" method="post">
 <p>Поиск по номеру телефона, формат: +7xxxxxxxxxx</p>
 <p>Введите номер: <input type="text" name="phone" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</html>
в скрипте использую переменную $_POST

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае $value равен:

```
[
   "pk"=> "Abonents",
   "fields" => [
     "sms" => "+71234567890",
     "name" => "Петров Петя Петрович",
   ]
]
```

Если вы ищете по номеру, которое лежит в sms то условие должно быть

```
if($value['fields']['sms'] == $phone) {...}
```

Если этих значений может не быть в массиве, то не забудьте добавить проверку на их наличие.

$key в вашем случае будет равен 0, ведь именно это и есть ключ массива по которому вы делаете foreach. Поэтому даже если вы что-то найдете таблица все равно будет пустой. Следует заменить на:

```
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$value['fields']['create_date'].'</td>
<td>'.$value['fields']['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$value['fields']['sms'].'</td>
<td>'.$value['fields']['contract_number'].'</td>
<td>'.$value['fields']['account_id'].'</td>
<td></td>
</tr>';
```

PS: Прочитайте [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339038/)([en](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)) чтобы узнать как решать такие проблемы в будущем.